# Should a bare bones Ubuntu install through VMware Fusion take up this much space?

Tags: disk-usage

I am trying to clean up some space on my Macbook Pro and I have Ubuntu running through VMware Fusion. I only use Ubuntu for a custom program that runs through the terminal and takes up about 5mb. Using the Mac OS get info on the virtual machine it is telling me Ubuntu takes up 31GB. Is that normal? I purged Libreoffice and basically all the major apps Ubuntu comes installed with. I would love to clean it up some more but don't know where the usage is coming from.

Thanks

Comment: 31 Gb is huge. A minimal install should take up much less then that, a desktop install takes 5 Gb.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements , server install takes 1 Gb.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since I don't spend a lot of time in Ubuntu I don't know the best way to go about figuring out how to free up that space. What do you recommend?

Comment: How much disk space does your custom program write in logs? Anyway, you can start searching for abnormalities with `du -ks * | sort -n` or `nautilus` if this is a graphical install. Or, do you mean to shrink the virtual drive?

Comment: It's a custom program my friend wrote. Its extremely small since it  is just outputting txt files. The total size it is currently taking up is 2mb. I just checked the disk space and I am using 3.6GB of 18GB with 14GB available in Ubuntu so does that mean the rest of the 31GB is being using by VMmare Fusion?